# Latex is not properly displayed

Tags: support, mathjax

My OS is Win7, and I've tried Firefox, IE9, and Chrome. None of them can display properly the Latex code. Yet, the code on mathoverflow is displayed properly.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there some proxy or firewall software on that PC or network that would prevent the MathJax dependency from loading?

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"></script>`

Can you try another PC?

Comment: Thanks, Jeff! Actually the Chinese censorship system, the GFW, has blocked MathJax.org, it seems. Which is very absurd. :(

Comment: I don't think this should be a problem now. Now I can access MathJax from China but not sure for how long :)

Comment: @SaiVenkat I think it's blocked again.

Comment: @MaoYiyi I have found a way to make MathJax work locally with greasemonkey and firefox. I will write about it and drop a message here

Comment: @SaiVenkat thanks alot. It sucks trying to understand all this latex, but on the bright side of things, it has helped me learn some latex.

Comment: @sai sure post an answer here describing how to do it, that will help everyone!